# Status bar tint color of the background of popover gets white after opening the popover

Tags: swift, statusbar, popover

I open a page programmatically with popover, the theme of the app is light so the status bar labels are black. But when the popover gets open, the the labels are status bar also gets white and nothing can be seen in the status bar. First I thought is it the problem of the popover page, but apparently, when the background page comes down, the tint color of the status bar changed. 
see the video here:
https://streamable.com/ehvjl4

how can I prevent this.

In the app, the `preferredStatusBarStyle`is white, and it works in any pages expect this case.

here is the code to open popover

```
 func showlistCard() {
     let vc = ContainerlistCard()
     vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
     present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

Any suggestion? many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to `ContainerListCard` class in `viewDidLoad()`

```
modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```